# Computing cross-validated $R^2$ from mean cross-validation error

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-squared, ridge-regression, glmnet

I am currently using `cv.glmnet` in R.  I would like to compute both a training $R^2$ and a cross-validated $R^2$.  R gives mean cross-validated error and for the fitted model gives a deviance ratio.

1. Is cross-validated $R^2$ equal to $1 - (\text{mean cross-validated error}/\text{variance in } y)$, or in R, `max(1-fit$cvm/var(y))` (where `fit$cvm` is a vector of mean cross-validated errors from all the regularized models tried)?
2. Is training $R^2$ the same thing as deviance ratio, i.e. `fit$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio` for the best model?
3. If the answer to 1 and 2 is yes, is this still true for a weighted `glmnet` fit, e.g. `cv.glmnet(x,y,weight=1/(1+y))`?

Comment: I have a suspicion that it might have something to do with the intercept being included into `cx`. Can you double-check by removing the column of ones from `cx` and `intercept=FALSE` from the `glmnet` call? What do you get then?

Comment: I tried that.  Very similar results - $R^2=0.9993311$ for a fit that looks average at best.

Comment: Hmm. And does it matter that you write `var(y)` in `max(1-fit$cvm/var(y))` and not `var(cy)`?

Comment: My.  Oh my days.  Yes it does!  Sorry this had such a trivial answer.  I shouldn't code tired.  Amoeba, assuming the answer to my questions 1+2 above is yes, please answer that and get the bounty.

Comment: If this looks confusing to anyone else it's because I have removed the faulty code from the question (which will be of no use to anybody else as it was basically a typo)

Comment: Looks like @amoeba has identified the issue and provided an answer. Why not award to him?

Comment: Because my family would probably kick me out if I opened my laptop on Christmas day!  Done now and thanks to @amoeba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The confusion was caused by a one-symbol typo in the originally posted code (see comments above).*

The answers are:

1. Yes.
2. Yes, but only for Gaussian GLM (as far as I understand from the [`glmnet` package description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf)).
3. Depends on how you define $R^2$ for the weighted regression. Deviance ratio will take weights into account (I don't know how exactly), whereas $R^2$ defined via mean error will (obviously) not.